# Create multiple csv files based on transpose

Tags: r, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
CustID  item    sales
1       a1      40
1       a2      40
1       a3      34
1       a4      42
1       a5      21
1       a6      22
2       a1      33
2       a2      30
2       a3      21
2       a4      11
2       a5      19
2       a6      20
```

I need to create 2 transposed data sets (they should be CSVs) such that each one contains item in groups of 3 each.....

OUTPUT:

```
csv1 (item 1-3)         
CustID  itema1  itema2  itema3
1         40      40     34
2         33      30     21

csv2 (item 4-6)         
CustID  itema4  itema5  itema6
1         42     21      22
2         11     19      20
```

Please help me out here

Comment: Have you tried a loop, using `reshape2::cast` to create the transpose and then writing out your files from within the loop itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an one-liner solution, but it does what you want.

First using a combination of `split` and `dcast` you can create and transpose the df.

```
> items <- split(df, df$item)
> 
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(do.call(rbind, items[1:3]), CustID~item )
  CustID a1 a2 a3
1      1 40 40 34
2      2 33 30 21

> dcast(do.call(rbind, items[4:6]), CustID~item )
  CustID a4 a5 a6
1      1 42 21 22
2      2 11 19 20
```

Then using `write.csv` you can create and save the data.frames into a csv file.

Here's all in one shot:

```
lapply(seq(1, length(items), 3), function(i){
  DF <- dcast(do.call(rbind, items[i:(i+2)]), CustID~item )
  write.csv(DF, file = paste0("DF", i, ".csv"))
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jilber, so in the above if i have 100K items and need to create 50 Csv's of 2000 columns each (that is csv1 will have column name of a1-a2000, csv2 will have column name of a2001-a4000 and so on...), and need to write each of the 50 csv files to drive, how do i put it in a loop framework?. Could you please help me out?

Comment: so, if i am doing it for 100k items, incrementing in groups of 2000 each.... it will be .,...    lapply(seq(1, length(items), 2000), function(i){
  DF <- dcast(do.call(rbind, items[i:(i+1999)]), CustID~item )
  write.csv(DF, file=paste0("DF", i, ".csv"))
})  where the datasets with be called DF2000 DF4000 etc..correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but not sure about the names of the dfs. I think names should be `"DF1.cvs", "DF2001.cvs", "DF4001.cvs", ..., "DF98001.cvs"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, using `xtabs` from base R:

```
x <- xtabs(sales ~ CustID + item, mydf)
x
#       item
# CustID a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
#      1 40 40 34 42 21 22
#      2 33 30 21 11 19 20
```

^^ That first step transposes the data for you.

```
fileout <- list(A = 1:3, B = 4:6)
```

Here, we have created a named list of the columns you want to export for each CSV. The names of the list items would be used for the CSV filenames.

Below is an example of how you can use `lapply` to write your CSV files.

```
lapply(seq_along(fileout), function(y) 
  write.csv(x[, fileout[[y]]], 
            file = paste(names(fileout[y]), ".csv", sep = "")))
```

Comment: +1. I always forget about `xtabs`, thanks for remind its existence