# How to transform elements in a list to dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have a little problem to solve in R. I have this list `a1` in R:

```
> a1
[[1]]
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  2  2  2
4 13 13 13
5 12 12 12
6 23 23 23
7 12 12 12

[[2]]
  x1 x2 x3
1  2  2  2
2  2  2  2
3  2  2  2
4 13 13 13
5 12 12 12
6 23 23 23
7 12 12 12

[[3]]
  x1 x2 x3
1  3  3  3
2  2  2  2
3  2  2  2
4 13 13 13
5 12 12 12
6 23 23 23
7 12 12 12
```

My problem is I don't get to extract all elements as data frames. For example I used this code for extract them as data frames but I got this error:

```
for(i in c(1:3))
{
  paste("a",i)=as.data.frame(a1[i])
}
Error in paste("a", i) = as.data.frame(a1[i]) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

My problem is the list has 20 elements and when I put `a1=as.data.frame(a1[1])` it works but I would have to write many lines because the `for` code showed doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your elements in a list , Better to use `lapply` to avoid the side effect . Try something like this for example:

```
 lapply(a1,write.csv)
```

**EDIT** add flodel answer:

```
filenames <- paste0(seq_along(a1), ".csv")
mapply(write.csv, a1, file = filenames)
```

Comment: @SimonO101 No need to give a name...`a1 <- list(data.frame(0),data.frame(1)) ;lapply(a1,write.csv);`

Comment: Dear @SimonO101 @agstudy when I use `lapply(a1,write.csv)` i got this `"","x1","x2","x3"
"1",1,1,1
"2",2,2,2
"3",2,2,2
"4",13,13,13
"5",12,12,12
"6",23,23,23
"7",12,12,12
"","x1","x2","x3"
"1",2,2,2
"2",2,2,2
"3",2,2,2
"4",13,13,13
"5",12,12,12
"6",23,23,23
"7",12,12,12
"","x1","x2","x3"
"1",3,3,3
"2",2,2,2
"3",2,2,2
"4",13,13,13
"5",12,12,12
"6",23,23,23
"7",12,12,12
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL`

Comment: and any .csv file is written in my directory

Comment: Rather, `filenames <- paste0(seq_along(a1), ".csv"); mapply(write.csv, a1, file = filenames);`

Comment: @flodel Thanks. I add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, two steps:

1. Add names to your list items.
2. Create the objects in your workspace using `list2env`.

Here's an example:

```
mylist <- list(data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)),
               data.frame(matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)),
               data.frame(matrix(9:12, ncol = 2)))
names(mylist) <- LETTERS[seq_along(mylist)]
mylist
# $A
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  3
# 2  2  4
# 
# $B
#   X1 X2
# 1  5  7
# 2  6  8
# 
# $C
#   X1 X2
# 1  9 11
# 2 10 12

A
# Error: object 'A' not found

list2env(mylist, envir=.GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

A
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  3
# 2  2  4
```

Comment: Yes..You should mention that it is better to keep your variables aggregated in a list ...

Comment: @agstudy, some things should be experienced to be learned, not told. :)

Comment: @agstudy This is due to I must save the elements in the list as excel files and I don't know how to make that with the elements of a list.

Comment: @Duck, as Excel files, or CSVs? I don't do much writing to Excel files from R, but with CSVs, it's pretty straightforward to use `write.csv` from within `lapply`.

Comment: @Duck, see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12257865/1270695) for writing a `list` of `data.frame`s to separate sheets in an Excel workbook.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I used `lapply(a1,write.csv)` but It doesn't work. It is easy to work with lists but I have problems exporting them

Comment: @Duck, is your list a named list? Look at [a recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155457/create-multiple-csv-files-based-on-transpose/19155923#19155923) I posted and see if that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Duck, try: `Names <- paste("file", 1:3, ".csv", sep="")
lapply(seq_along(a1), function(x) write.csv(mylist[[x]], file = Names[x]))`. (This assumes you only have 3 list items. Modify the `paste` step according to your actual scenario.)